# Managing synchronization options in User Profile Service Application using Powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-server, user-profile, synchronization, sharepoint-farm

I am trying to manage the synchronization options in SharePoint Farm using Powershell.

I would like to change the "Use SharePoint Profile Synchronization" to "Enable External Identity Manager" by code to automate the process of configuration of user permissions and their options.

http://thesharepointfarm.com/2013/06/using-an-external-identity-manager-for-sharepoint-user-profile-synchronization/

The way it is done manually is: **SharePoint Administration -> Manage Service Applications -> User Profile Service Application -> Configure Synchronization Settings -> Synchronization Options**

Is there any way of accessing and editing this option by use of Powershell? I've already tried to use commands like `Set-SPProfileServiceApplication` and `Set-SPRequestManagementSettings` but I cannot find it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks Like this is not supported by MSFT so that we don't any solution far. Even [Spence Harber respond](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/fe2330d9-83e7-419f-a091-f00b4a7034b7/configure-synchronization-connections-with-powershell-user-profile?forum=sharepointadminprevious) on one of post.

But this code from Technet Gallery.

http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Create-User-Profile-Sync-e9ec0cf7

http://blog.karstein-consulting.com/2013/09/11/create-user-profile-sync-connection-for-sharepoint-2010-by-script-a-supported-approach/